# Event Arguments from onserverclick of an HTML button with runat server

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm using bootstrap html buttons on my page. But the problem am facing is I cant pass any arguments to server side function. 
As an example this is my HTML button code

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="btn_save" runat="server"  onserverclick="saveuser"  clientidmode='Static'><i class="fa fa-save"></i>Save</button>
```

And my sever side function is this

```
Sub saveuser()
'''' Code to save user
End Sub
```

But my requirement is to pass an argument to this save user from the onserverclick attribute. I tried lots of ways.. But no help..

Actually my intention is to call the same function from different buttons and do the stuff based on the arguments passed.

Comment: That method is an optimal solution I guess coz if I pass parameter 1 we only need to use 1 serverside function for different buttons instead of different click events for 5-6 buttons.. Why we needs those viewstate or hidden fields if an argument is enough.. thats why i thought..

Comment: The data you are trying to access during this particular button click on the server-side, is already there, either in the viewstate or stored in some input-based controls (like textbox, hidden fields, etc) on the page itself - because people usually put it "there" during page load or whatever event. Hence, on postback of your specific button these are available to you that way. What makes you want all such data to be part of the event argument?

Comment: Explain what you mean by "pass parameter 1". Further explain how you associate some data with the button in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to distinguish by the button's ID. If you have `onserverclick="userbutton_click"`, you can do this in code-behind

```
Protected Sub userbutton_click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)

    Dim myButton = CType(sender, HtmlButton)
    Dim buttonID = myButton.ClientID

    Select Case buttonID
        Case "btn_save"
            'Do something
        Case "btn_delete"
            'Do some other thing
        Case Else

    End Select

End Sub
```

Here we are distinguishing the button using `id` which should be unique.

Comment: Thats a nice idea.. But thats not a perfect way.. isnt it? Sorry.. I was just thinking about a correct way to achieve args and sender together..

Comment: No that's not. If you are using `asp:Button` things would be much easier though. I was also wondering how to send args here ;)

Comment: asp:buttons main drawback I guess is its not possible to wrap other elements (such as div or spans..) inside it. But we can achieve this using link buttons.. But I was using normal buttons, honestly with out any specific reason.. :) Working in bootstrap and its priorities buttons..
I was just thinking about that argument method coz with a single function we can identify the buttons based on the arguments instead of writing dft click events.. Sorry I know this can be achieved in lots of ways like button call from the differnt click events.. But was checking any solution for this arg method..

Comment: thats the reason why i moved to `mvc`. much saner markup. i still love webforms. i started from there. so...

Comment: Im with classic dot net for the last 8 yrs.. Honestly interested to start with MVC but projects am doing now required to be in classic .NET... So not getting a chance or simply dont know anything with MVC.. :)